# Context initialization failed Error with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I'm receiving an exception when I try to start my Spring MVC application with a deployed war file on a tomcat8 (java 1.8_65):

> Context initialization failed Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in biz.aspsol.solarix.init.configuration.WebAppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinTable.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;

What is strange is that I can run the application without problems from my Intellij Idea however the deployment with the war file does not work.

Here is my maven dependency tree:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.8.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.10.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- ognl:ognl:jar:3.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.unbescape:unbescape:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.4.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.6:runtime (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjtools:jar:1.8.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.velocity:velocity-tools:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-chain:commons-chain:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- sslext:sslext:jar:1.2-0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.struts:struts-core:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.struts:struts-taglib:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.struts:struts-tiles:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.4-1202-jdbc42:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
[INFO] +- com.braintreepayments.gateway:braintree-java:jar:2.49.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-pdf-itext5:jar:9.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-core:jar:9.0.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:jar:1.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.pdfbox:fontbox:jar:1.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.pdfbox:jempbox:jar:1.8.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.52:compile
[INFO] +- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk15on:jar:1.52:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.52:compile
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20150729:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.maps:google-maps-services:jar:0.1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] \- com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.5.7:compile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for the problem. I have included the hibernate-jpa-2.1-api dependency into my pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have an older version of JPA api deployed in your tomcat.
That is why you see no exceptions when deploying from IntelliJ.

`indexes` attribute was introduced to `@JoinTable` in JPA 2.1. If you use older version of JPA you'll get the exact same exception at runtime.

Check that there are no other JPA api jars in the `$CATALINA_BASE/lib` folder

Comment: The $CATALINA_BASE/lib folder in the remote Tomcat and also the  instance run from IntelliJ contain both the same versions of jar files and there is also no JPA api jar at all.

Comment: still the exception is caused by the older version of JPA. Unpack the war file and see if there is an older version somewhere inside

Comment: I have resolved the problem by including the hibernate-jpa-2.1-api dependency in my pom.xml. Really strange as I thought that the API is already included in the project according to the maven tree in org.hibernate:hibernate-core.